# access a list by index in django template inside a for statement?

Tags: python, django, list, loops, templates

I'm using django 1.11 and python 3.5.2.

This is the important part of my code in `views.py`

```
ListaValoresLeidosXML = []

for sec in secciones:
    print(sec.contenidoxml)

    treexml = ET(fromstring(sec.contenidoxml))
    Lista = []

    for child in treexml.findall('caracteristica'):
        nombre = child.find('nombre').text
        Lista.append(nombre)
    ListaValoresLeidosXML.append(Lista)

for lista in ListaValoresLeidosXML:
    for valor in lista:
        print(valor)
    print('*****')

return render(request, 'editarCatElem.html', {
      'elemento': ElemSeg,
      'link': tutorial,
      'subelementos': subelementos,
      'secciones': secciones,
      'listaXML' : ListaValoresLeidosXML
      })
```

I'm reading a string field in my database, it contents a xml-formatted text, using `treexml` I can get all the attributes.

Finally I have a list of lists, each list have values of a section, it means if I have `n` sections then I'll have `n` lists inside a list.

I'm sending a list called ListaXML to my template.

In my template I'm trying to iterate it

```
{% for seccion in secciones %}

    <div style="display: block" class="form-group">
        <div style="display: block" class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="nombreSeccion">Sección <span class="required">*</span></label>
            <div class="col-md-2"><input type="text" value='{{ seccion.nombre }}' id="nombreSeccion" name="secciones[][nombreSeccion]" class="form-control col-md-2"></div>
            <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="descSeccion">Descripción <span class="required">*</span></label>
            <div class="col-md-2"><input type="text" value='{{ seccion.descripcion }}' id="descSeccion" name="secciones[][descripcionSeccion]" class="form-control col-md-2"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-7">

            <div class="form-horizontal form-label-left" style="background:lightblue; padding:8px;">

                    {% for caracteristica in listaXML %} # <-- Here is the problem!!

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="nombreCampo">Campo <span class="required">*</span></label>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <input type="text" value='{{ caracteristica }}' name="secciones[][campos][][nombreCampo]" id="nombreCampo" class="form-control col-md-2">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    {% endfor %}

                <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary col-sm-offset-0 col-sm-3" onclick="agregarCampo(event);"><i class="fa fa-plus"> </i> Agregar campo</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-3" onclick="eliminarCampo(event);"><i class="fa fa-minus"> </i> Eliminar campo</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

{% endfor %}
```

The problem is I need to do this with every repetition:

```
{% for caracteristica in listaXML.0 %}
{% for caracteristica in listaXML.1 %}
{% for caracteristica in listaXML.2 %}
{% for caracteristica in listaXML.3 %}
...
```

I need to increment the final number (the index of the list).

I've tried

```
{% for caracteristica in listaXML.forloop.counter0 %}
```

or

```
{% for caracteristica in listaXML.{{forloop.counter0}} %}
```

but it doesn't work.

Any idea on how the code works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you just need a double for loop :

```
{% for lista in listaXML %}
    {% for caracteristica in lista %}
        <div class="form-group">
        [...]
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Yeah it works, but It gives me a wrong rendering. I need to replace the index with a variable

Comment: @AngelPineda  you need to force indexes at listaXML level or sub-lista ? Maybe it's easier to change the object before the loop, just an idea, i'm not sure what you expect exactly

Comment: @PRMoreu I needed to force indexes at listaXML level, finally I couldn't. I had to modify the parameters sent to template.

Comment: @AngelPineda sometimes it's better to let the logic inside the views, rather than in the templates